# NGINX HTTP/HTTPS Redirecting to HTTPS even though no instructions appear to be in server block

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have the following in my `nginx.conf` which is working great for HTTPS when I go to `https://sub.mydomain.com`. I needed to also allow `HTTP` (hence the listen 80).

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.mydomain.io;

  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/mydomain.key;

  ssl on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

For some reason, when I try to hit `http://sub.mydomain.com` it is still redirecting me to `https`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this actually the configuration you're using? Better run `nginx -t`.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's HSTS policy.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ssl on` directive - it works for entire server/virtualhost, no matter will you specify `ssl` after `listen` or not.

(specified in docs:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl)

i.e.:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.mydomain.io;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name *.mydomain.io;

  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/mydomain.key;

  ssl on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```